# GitHub action to run command and add commit if I type comment

Tags: github-actions

My objective is to get to the point where I can type `/run-black` as a comment on a pull request in GitHub, and then GitHubActions will run `black .` on the pull request's branch and add a commit.

The use case is that sometimes casual contributors make a small pull request to my library (e.g. fixing a typo), and I'd like to be able to just write a comment like `/run-black` to have the `black` formatter run on their files before I merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the action [Slash Command Dispatch](https://github.com/peter-evans/slash-command-dispatch). Add a `repo` scoped PAT with the name `PAT` to your secrets and create two workflows with the following definitions.

```
name: Slash Command Dispatch
on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created]
jobs:
  slashCommandDispatch:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Slash Command Dispatch
        uses: peter-evans/slash-command-dispatch@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
          issue-type: pull-request
          commands: |
            run-black
```

```
on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types: [run-black-command]
jobs:
  runBlack:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: ${{github.event.client_payload.pull_request.head.repo.full_name}}
          ref: ${{github.event.client_payload.pull_request.head.ref}}
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
      - name: Slash Command Dispatch
        run: black .
      - run: |
          git config --local user.email "41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
          git config --local user.name "github-actions[bot]"
          git commit -m "Run black" -a
          git push
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but I got the error " 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use

    git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>"  Any suggestion for how to push to the pull request's branch?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity try my edit, but it only works if the branch that is pulled from is either in your repository or the PR allows you to push to their fork

Comment: Is there a way to execute this action with an app token instead of PAT?